# What is the difference between automapper.extensions.microsoft.dependencyinjection and automapper nuget packages?

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core

I found two nuget packages for integration  mapper in my .net core 3.1 project and I only use automapper.extensions.microsoft.dependencyinjection and it works, and I see a another approach with the AutoMapper Nuget , and in first one I saw dependencies of AutoMapper, but in my example it works without this.

[image]

Comment: YOUR example works without it. Translate: The small part of Automapper you use is not using any reference to the main automapper so they are not loaded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The NuGet package `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` will also load the dependend packages (listed under dependencies) into your project.

It is the same as if you would manually add

- AutoMapper
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions
- AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

to your project.

Answer (score -1):

when we use Automapper extension , then we need to register the dependency in startup file as well.